# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:on near line 1, column 102 [FROM com.strutsProject.dto.EventClubTb

Tags: hibernate

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 102 [FROM com.strutsProject.dto.EventClubTb  as C  inner join com.strutsProject.dto.AchievementsTb as  A  on A.EVENTNAME=C.EVENTNAME ]

String hql = "FROM com.strutsProject.dto.EventClubTb  as C  inner join com.strutsProject.dto.AchievementsTb as  A  on A.EVENTNAME=C.EVENTNAME ";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

@Entity
@Table(name="clubevent")

```
private static final long serialVersionUID=-8767337896773261247L; 
private Long id;
private String eventname;
private AchievementsTb actb;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "actbeventname")`enter code here
public AchievementsTb getActb() {`enter code here`
    return actb;
}
public void setActb(AchievementsTb actb) {
    this.actb = actb;
}

public String getEventname() {
    return eventname;
}
public void setEventname(String eventname) {
    this.eventname = eventname;
}
```

@Entity
@Table(name="achievements")
public class AchievementsTb extends ViewAllGridList 
{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID=-8767337896773261247L; 
private Long id;
private String eventname; 
public String getEventname() {
    return eventname;
}
public void setEventname(String eventname) {
    this.eventname = eventname;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `EventClubTb` is associated with `AchievementsTb`:

```
FROM com.strutsProject.dto.EventClubTb as C join C.achievementsTb as A
```

Otherwise you can use classic theta-style join:

```
FROM com.strutsProject.dto.EventClubTb as C, com.strutsProject.dto.AchievementsTb as A
where A.EVENTNAME=C.EVENTNAME
```